# How to extract the files of ImageNet-1K dataset for each class separately?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, imagenet

I have downloaded the ImageNet1K data from https://huggingface.co/datasets/imagenet-1k/tree/main/data . However, the tar files include images with the filenames `ILSVRC2012_val_00000009_n03794056.JPEG` . Is there any script to contract the files in the following format (each class have a folder in train and validation folder)?

```
│imagenet/
├──train/
│  ├── n01440764
│  │   ├── n01440764_10026.JPEG
│  │   ├── n01440764_10027.JPEG
│  │   ├── ......
│  ├── ......
├──val/
│  ├── n01440764
│  │   ├── ILSVRC2012_val_00000293.JPEG
│  │   ├── ILSVRC2012_val_00002138.JPEG
│  │   ├── ......
│  ├── ......
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer yes I did, please have a look into this link https://gist.github.com/BIGBALLON/8a71d225eff18d88e469e6ea9b39cef4

Comment: If you add that link as an answer, I'm sure others would appreciate it :)